# Is `size_t` part of the standard library, or part of the C language itself?

Tags: c

As a programmer, I can't use `size_t` unless I include `stddef.h`. This seems to imply this is a type defined in the C standard library. However, `sizeof` is a built-in language operator that returns a `size_t`. It seems weird to me that a built-in language feature would rely on the standard library. Is `size_t` "owned" by the library or the language?

Comment: In C18 "§7.19 Common definitions <stddef.h> ... `size_t` which is the unsigned integer type of the result of the `sizeof` operator." Note that it isn't a fixed size: it is the size needed to cover all the use cases in an implementation, which is why it is in a library. Similarly with, say, `long` which has a minimum size which an implementation can define.

Comment: Although `<stddef.h>` is the smallest header that defines `size_t`, a number of other headers do too — notably `<stdio.h>`, `<string.h>`, and `<stdlib.h>` (the big three standard headers).  It is a rare program that uses none of these.  Of course, small files containing library code may not need them, and in such cases, including `<stddef.h>` is a good idea.  Also, standalone headers where none of the interfaces uses anything from the big three standard headers except `size_t` should include `<stddef.h>` instead.

Comment: " It seems weird to me that a built-in language feature would rely on the standard library" --> Agreed.  I am confident `size_t` is in a `<*.h>` as it was easier to do so than make it native-ly defined in the language - in those early days.

Comment: `size_t` is an identifier and is not part of the language. The type of `size_t` is part of the language ;-)

Comment: This is the realization of a committee invention; no worthy team would be so daft.

Answer (score 3):

Is `size_t` part of the standard library, or part of the C language itself?

The standard library, and the contents of the headers defined in clause 7 of the 2018 C standard, are part of the C language; everything specified in the C standard, including preprocessing, is part of the C language.

(In particular, the compiler is allowed to use knowledge of what routines in the standard library do even if the headers are not included. For example, if `memcpy` is used with file scope, the compiler is allowed to replace `memcpy(&a, &b, sizeof *a)` with `a = b` (assuming `a` and `b` are the same type) even if no standard library header is included.)

However, `size_t` is not a keyword reserved in 6.4.1, where the keywords are listed and is not specified in clause 6, which you might consider specifies a “core” part of the C language.

> However, `sizeof` is a built-in language operator that returns a `size_t`.

`sizeof` returns a value with some type described as `size_t` in the text, but that identifier, `size_t` is not defined in the absence of including `<stddef.h>` or possibly other library header files. The type of `sizeof` is known to the compiler but does not necessarily have a name or may have some internal name known to the compiler, such as `__size_t`, or it may be a standard type, such as `unsigned int`.

Including `stddef.h` makes this type available to the programmer by defining the identifier `size_t` suitably.

Comment: There's also `_Alignof` and (if you've included `<stdalign.h>`) `alignof` that also return a value of type `size_t`.  Section 6 of the standard, "the C language proper", makes several mentions of `size_t`, but — as you say — the type is not define in section 6, but it is defined in `<stddef.h>`; it's also defined in each of the "big three" headers: `<stdio.h>`, `<stdlib.h>`, and `<string.h>`.